# VirtualBox NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) Mac

Tags: macos, virtualization, virtualbox

So, I restarted my Mac in the morning and I receive this error while trying to start my normal VBox but it did not start instead it gave in an error. This is the error image [image]

Comment: Did yo perform an update of any kind (macOS and/or VirtualBox especailly)?  It's also helpful if you let us know what version of VB and macOS you're using.

Comment: Its not updated This is the the Version 5.1.14 r112924 (Qt5.6.2)

Comment: @Allani have figured out a way from this problem but can you look at this problem = https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/324154/failed-to-open-create-the-internal-network-hostinterfacenetworking-en0-virtual

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So, To fix this issue you will need to be in an admin account then you will need the VirtualBox .dmg file download then you will open the dmg you should see something like this [image]
Click on the VirtualBox_uninstall.tool file. Then you will see your terminal open and give you this output

```
Last login: Thu May  3 18:47:27 on ttys000
macname:~ user_name$ /Volumes/VirtualBox/VirtualBox_Uninstall.tool ;        exit;

Welcome to the VirtualBox uninstaller script.

The following files and directories (bundles) will be removed:
 /usr/local/bin/VirtualBox
 /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage
 /usr/local/bin/VBoxVRDP
 /usr/local/bin/VBoxHeadless
 /usr/local/bin/vboxwebsrv
 /usr/local/bin/VBoxBugReport
 /usr/local/bin/VBoxBalloonCtrl
 /usr/local/bin/VBoxAutostart
 /usr/local/bin/VBoxDTrace
 /usr/local/bin/vbox-img
 /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.virtualbox.startup.plist
 /Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/
 /Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/VBoxDrv.kext/
 /Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/VBoxUSB.kext/
 /Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/VBoxNetFlt.kext/
 /Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/VBoxNetAdp.kext/
 /Applications/VirtualBox.app/

 And the following KEXTs will be unloaded: org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv

 Do you wish to uninstall VirtualBox (Yes/No)?
```

type Yes

```
The uninstallation processes requires administrative privileges
because some of the installed files cannot be removed by a normal
user. You may be prompted for your password now...

Please enter your_id password:
```

Enter Your password *YOU MUST ME ADMIN* OR ROOT

Then Once the terminal is done uninstalling.

open the VirtualBox.dmg again and follow the steps to install it then at the end it will say installing failed or some kind of error.

Open: System Preferences > Security & Privacy . then on the bottom of that window you will see a message to allow access to the virtual box just click that and open  Virtual Box you will be good to go but after this i ran into another problem which is not that improtent related to Bridge Adapter. :

[Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-en0' VirtualBox?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/324154/failed-to-open-create-the-internal-network-hostinterfacenetworking-en0-virtual)

Comment: When I read this answer I gave it a solid 1% chance of working. But it worked, bravo! You saved me a bunch of time.

Comment: I follow you message exactly. I stopped at `it will say installing failed or some kind of error.` i went to Security & Privacy, nothing about Virtualbox. what to do?, i am admin.

Comment: Okay it worked. the thing i should allow it was `American Orcale, Inc` nothing about virtualbox. that is way i got confused

Comment: I've uninstalled and reinstalled, but am not seeing the option to Allow under Security & Privacy. Any other way I can force it? Using Big Sur 11.3.1.

Comment: (Using macOS 11.4 Big Sur) Since I originally installed via Homebrew, I decided to try applying this answer via brew before resorting to a conventional download and install. The following worked for me: `csrutil status` (make sure it says "System Integrity Protection status: enabled.") Then `brew uninstall --cask virtualbox` and `brew install --cask virtualbox` folowed by a reboot to allow the kext to activate. All my previous vboxes were still listed and they worked. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @BrunoBronosky oddly enough OP has xCode. I have uninstalled using virtualbox_uninstall.tool and again via brew, and received an error `$$ Error: You have not agreed to the Xcode license. Please resolve this by running: sudo xcodebuild -license accept`. Very odd. Wondering if correlation, missing link?

Comment: @dnaatwork.com asks, "correlation"? Slightly. A reductive summary could be: These issues occur when engineers don't follow the install and upgrade path that Apple anticipates and has designed their their test process to verify. Mitigate these by migrating your system state to that which is expected. My state drift was a missing kernel extension. Your drift was a missing `licenseAccepted` plist entry. Both would have been avoided by a Normie installing via App Store and launching the Xcode GUI 1 time. You and I, "Think Different". ☮️❤️

Comment: I was on version `6.1.30`. I switched to latest version `7.0.4` (https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/7.0.4/) and all went back to normal. Previous version uninstalled with `VirtualBox_Uninstall.tool` as mentioned above. I am on MacOS Venture `13.0.1`. If you do don't forget to also update your Guest Additions using `VBoxGuestAdditions_7.0.4.iso` (My guest is Windows Server)

Comment: @BrunoBronosky It says`System Integrity Protection status: unknown (Custom Configuration).` So now what? How do I make it say `System Integrity Protection status: enabled.`? Running `sudo csrutil enable` responds with `csrutil: This tool needs to be executed from Recovery OS.`

Answer (score 7):

I realize this is an old question, but as its the number 1 result on google I though I would mention. If you are having this problem on big sur 11.1 and reinstalling hasn't fixed the issue, check and see if you have SIP enabled. In my case it was disabled and re-enabling it did the trick. I suspect that if it's disabled, you know how to enable it, but just in case: reboot into recovery mode, sign in with your user account, go to utilities > terminal and run

```bsh
csrutil enable && reboot
```

This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: +1 to this! macOS 11.1 Big Sur with Virtualbox 6.1.6 produced 'NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)' due to SIP being disabled.

Comment: That was the issue! Thank you so much!

Comment: before apply this, you can check if it is alread enabled by `csrutil status`

Comment: my SIP is indeed disabled. But after I enable it uninstall and reinstall virtualbox, I'm still not able to see the Allow App prompt in Security & Privacy

Answer (score 2):

I got this when I was trying to restore a suspended session. The fix was to click the "Discard" button (down arrow icon) and just discard the saved machine state. It's at least faster that uninstall/reinstall, I'd try it first.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was afraid to press Discard because I thought it would discard the VM, not the saved state. This worked for me when an ininstall/reinstall did not.

Comment: I having the same problem first time i installed this. have not run it before. where is the discard button?