# Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-en0' VirtualBox?

Tags: network, wifi, high-sierra, virtualization, virtualbox

I download VirtualBox 5.2.10 r122088 (Qt5.6.3) On my macOS High Sierra. I set up my virtual machines but I cant have bridged adapter apparently. it was working in the last one but in this one, it just Gives me an error whenever I do AttachedTo: Bridged Adapter, Name: en0: WIFI(Air-Port) and in the advanced Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (82540EM)[image]

And when I start I get an error: Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-en0' (VERR_SUPDRV_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND).
Failed to attach the network LUN (VERR_SUPDRV_COMPONENT_NOT_FOUND).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and then I solved it.

My installation environment is macOS High Sierra.

1. Install the extension package Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack corresponding to the VBox version
2. Create a new virtual machine
3. Set the network to bridge the network card
4. Start and select the image installation
5. During the installation process, open [Network and Host Name], Ethernet, then you can see the LAN IP
6. Continue to complete the installation.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please note that all posts must be in English; most people here don't understand Chinese.

Answer (score -1):

So, This not the correct answer but i solved it like this i download VM-ware fusion and set it up using this youtube video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfLGKJM3bsI&t=315s