# Cannot start any Virtual Machine anymore on High Sierra

Tags: macos, virtualization, virtualbox

I just switched from Sierra to High Sierra for some reason, and Virtualbox doesn't work anymore.
All my machines (Debian, Windows etc), newly created or existing, show that message when started:

```
The virtual machine 'Serveur PHP 5' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).

Error code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)

Component: 
MachineWrap

Interface: 
IMachine {5047460a-265d-4538-b23e-ddba5fb84976}
```

It's not linked to [VirtualBox NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/323960/virtualbox-ns-error-failure-0x80004005-mac) :

- No "Kernel Driver" error message
- No "Security and Privacy" message
- Discard not working
- Reinstalling does not solve anything.

VB Version : 6.1.2

macOS Version : 10.13.6

Any idea?

Many thanks

Comment: To remove the duplicate flag you have to hit the reopen button...

Comment: So, less info than the dupe...  upgrade?  Clean install?  How did you back up restore virtual box?  Version of VB?

Comment: @klanomath I dont have a reopen button. Plus if you read the post you'd have seen its not a duplicate. Let me quote myself "It's not linked to VirtualBox NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) Mac"

Comment: @allan no upgrade, latest version, clean install.

Comment: @klanomath plus its on your "closed" notice: "If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one." that's what I did.

Comment: relax, it's in review queue, five people/ one moderator/ one gold badge holder would open it. It is advised to browse [tag:virtualbox]

Comment: No upgrade?  How did you get to a High Sierra?  What version of VB?  how did you migrate your VMs?  Please help us help you by providing details.  Saying it’s not a dupe because none of the same things happened despite the exact same error message is difficult enough, but vague and incomplete answers defiantly don’t help.  Remember, we can’t see over your shoulder.

Comment: Reinstall *what* doesn’t help?  Reinstalling VB?  macOS?  The VM itself?

Comment: Excuse me, yes I indeed upgraded to High Sierra, using the App Store. My version of  VB is the latest one as I said, so 6.1.2 so be precise. I didn't migrate my VMs, I don't know what it means; and anyway new VMs have that problem too.
Reinstalling VB didn't help.

Comment: You get the same error message when you create a new VM from scratch?  As far as your VMs go, you can’t just copy them back.  You need to *add* them back to VBox ( there’s a function to do that). Re: the upgrade, I’m trying to determine *how* and *what* you did not from where you obtained it.  Try to be more specific like “upgraded macOS by doing whatever you did.”  Just saying “reinstalling didn’t solve..” doesn’t say what or how you reinstalled whatever it was

Comment: "You get the same error message when you create a new VM from scratch?" Yes. “reinstalling didn’t solve..” was related to the answers given in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/323960/virtualbox-ns-error-failure-0x80004005-mac , that mostly all suggest to reinstall VB.